# Color transition background html

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, background

I'm making a website and as a background I would really like to have transitioning colors. I've done some research on the internet but so far I've only been able to find solutions that include hovering over the object while I want it as a background that starts as soon as you open the page.

Can somebody help me or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: writing code would be a good start...

Answer (score 0):

This would be the 1st place I would check. Learn it and then apply it to your website. [Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/). Good luck.

Comment: if this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as the accepted answer so i receive credit. Thank you!